# Add trailing forward slash to redirect when trying to access http

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to have a redirect, when not in server index, to go to the https, non-www version of my site. Currently when typing `http://example.com/login` the redirect goes to `https://example.comlogin` which obviously gives me an error.

Here is my `default-ssl.conf` file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin email@gmail.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            RewriteEngine On

            # Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

            # Include trailing slash on directory
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

            # Force HTTPS and remove WWW
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also have in my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

My `example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
  ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
  <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
  ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
  <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where are the rest of the redirects?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not quite sure what you mean. My understanding of apache/webservers is not the greatest

Comment: None of the redirects you posted would cause the issue you report. The problem must be somewhere else. You need to post the entire configuration, or at least all of the relevant parts.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ok, I've added my other configuration file. I've suspected that maybe having two different files isn't the norm but I also have an SSL so I'm not quite sure. Both are also in `sites-enabled`

Comment: Again, there's still nothing in what you've posted that would trigger such a redirect. Although 2 of the redirects in the first vHost would actually result in a double-slash issue (not no-slash)! However, redirecting from HTTP in the HTTPS vHost isn't going work, and having multiple vHost wrappers is not going to help either - only 1 can be active for any request. You have a redirect that supposedly removes www, however, none of the vHost containers appear to accept requests to www? Does your application perform any redirects?

Comment: Why not just add a simple `Redirect / https://example.com/` in virtualhost 80 instead of all that htaccess mess?